# Error when compiling ReverseString program, Java

Tags: java, string, reverse

Please forgive my extremely limited experience in Java. I am taking a basic Java course at school, and we are working on our first project. I have done a bit of research on what I need to get done, but I couldn't find something that applies to my problem. I need to make a program that reverses a string completely. We cannot use any `String` class other than String; no `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`. We also need to do it through input and message boxes, rather than the console. What is wrong with my code?

```
/*
ReverseString
*/


import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ReverseString
{
    public static void main (String[] args);
    {
        String str;
        for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0;  i--)
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The output I received states an error on line 11. `Error: missing method body, or declare abstract`

Thanks for helping, and again, I apologize if it's something obvious. We just started learning two weeks ago.

[UPDATE]

I have taken some of your advice, now I'm getting another error.

```
/*
ReverseString
*/


import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ReverseString
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
      {
    String str = "";
    int frame = 0;
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Input a string.");
    for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0;  i--)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your reversed string is " + str); 
      }
}
```

Error is on line 17. Here's the exact output, for the person who asked for it earlier.

> 1 error found:
>   File: C:\Users\mpach0928\ReverseString.java  [line: 17]
>   Error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.awt.Component

Comment: what is the full stack trace? (in other words, what exactly is printed along the error you wrote?)

Comment: Well, you've not given `str` a value. What string do you intend to reverse?

Comment: Even after removing typo, you will get NullPointerException because you haven't initialized `str`

Answer (score 5):

A semicolon too much there:

`public static void main (String[] args);`<--- remove this `;`

Comment: You beat me to it -_- Here's your upvote :)

Answer (score 3):

You've got a semi-colon that you should not have... like this i pointed

```
public static void main (String[] args); << HERE
      {
```

Comment: haha i was faster but you are also right xD

Answer (score 1):

Your

> String str;

Is not initialized.

Use

> Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
String str = "";
str = scanner.nex();
```

For giving a value to you str via console.